# Reuse the Same Variable For Multiple TryParse() Calls

Tags: c#, code-reuse, tryparse

I did some reading on this, and from questions *similar* to mine, it looks like what I am about to ask might not be (easily) possible... But I wanted to verify anyway. Maybe all those questions were from an older version of C#/.NET, and the thing has been implemented recently.

Anyway. I have a switch-case statement in one of my classes, whose purpose is essentially to take an int (`typeID`) and string (`value`) and check whether the `value` can be parsed as the data type indicated by `typeID`. For example, here is part of what I have now:

```
    case 1:
        char charret;
        return char.TryParse(value, out charret);
    case 2:
        Regex re = new Regex(Constants.REGEX_ALPHANUMERIC);
        return re.IsMatch(value);
    case 3:
        bool boolret;
        return bool.TryParse(value, out boolret);
    //And so on...
```

What I would like to do is to be able to avoid the `char`/`bool` instantiation you see in cases 1 & 3. Ideally, I would like to just have the return statement. It's not a big deal (obviously), but it would be nice if I could make this more (even more) compact.

Comment: Can't you just declare the variable before the switch?

Comment: You should store the `Regex` instance instead of re-parsing it every time.

Comment: @Anon, I would, if it could all boil down to one type. Which it can't.

Comment: @SLaks, I should. I will. Good call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's inherently impossible.

Variables passed as `out` parameters must exactly match the parameter type.

Comment: That's a shame. I was hoping that since C# has support for anonymous functions, I could apply similar principles here as well. Not a biggie though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to avoid declaring a variable when you are calling a function with an out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This post might be helpful as it does a generic TryParse (if it is available):

http://toadcode.blogspot.com/2010/10/generic-object-tryparse.html

Comment: It's definitely interesting. If was doing more serious parsing, I would probably look into something like that, but in this case, it's really just 8 cases in this switch-case block - and that's it.